# Adding padding to the header pushes the header to the right, solution?

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is my code.
I'm still a beginner in CSS
that's why I'm asking this question please help me i've tried everything.
the problem is when ever i add padding to the header it seem like its pushing all the elements in the header to the right
am I missing something here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>To do list app</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #25b99a;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.15);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

}

header input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter an activity..">
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide padding code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to make a header that doesn't pass the right side of the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a style of `box-sizing: border-box` to the header. This will mean that the width of the header (100%) is calculated *including* the padding. The end result will be that width + padding will add up to 100%. The `box-sizing` style is also well supported in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract the left and right padding from the header width using:

```
width: calc(100vw - 30px);
```

Here's the snippet:

```css
header {
    width: calc(100vw - 30px);
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #25b99a;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44,62,80,0.15);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;

}

header input {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border: 0px;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

```html
    <header>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter an activity..">
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is when you add the padding you break the 100% width and add a padding to it making it 100% + 2*padding. Even when the borders are not there problem persists, only you don't notice it, try typing as many letters so input fills up and notice how right side will still be bad.

In modern browsers only
For header:

```
display: flex;
```

For input:

```
align-items: stretch;
```

Flex display should take everything into account.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the padding on top and down if you don't need the sides. And your header is moving because it has to move 15px to it right to make space for the padding in it left.

```
padding-top:15px
padding-down:15px
```

Comment: padding-down doesn't exist. It's padding-bottom